# Javascript cant get value from PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want make data exist checker.
**data.check.php:**

```
<?php
    $nick   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nick']);
    $query = mysql_query("select * from tb_user WHERE nick='$nick'");
    $nick_exist = mysql_num_rows($query);
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var nick_exist = "<?php echo $nick_exist; ?>";
</script>
```

and this for $POST data
**input.data.js**

```
var v_nick = $('input:text[name=nick]').val();
$.post('data.check.php', {nick: v_nick} ,function() {
    if(nick_exist){
        window.alert('Choose another nick please!');
    }
});
```

I dont know where is the problem and my windows.alert is not running :(

thanks u

Comment: When is input.data.js initialized?

Comment: just show us what is you html gererated is `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var nick_exist = "";
</script>` ???

Comment: make the php file to print 'true' or 'false', and use the printed to make the $.post inside condition

$.post('data.check.php', {nick: v_nick} ,function(response) 
{ alert(response);
}

Comment: I agree with @Yair.R you even don't need that `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var nick_exist = "<?php echo $nick_exist; ?>";
</script>` just `echo $nick_exist;` to the stream. and check `response` on javascript side

Comment: use can print a json in data.check.php page and get json by jquery .ajax

Comment: @Mouser when user click submit then **input.data.js** is running and use **data.check.php** for checking if not exist nick

Comment: @Yair.R Im newbie in javascript and I just learning about AJAX :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this get the count in php then return it to js:

**NOTE:** Please do not use **mysql** it is deprecated now start using **mysqli** or **pdo**.

**data.check.php:**

```
<?php
    $nick   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nick']);
    $query = mysql_query("select * from tb_user WHERE nick='$nick'");
    $nick_exist = mysql_num_rows($query);
    echo json_encode(array('count'=> $nick_exist));//send result to javascript
?>
```

**input.data.js**

```
var v_nick = $('input:text[name=nick]').val();
$.post('data.check.php', {nick: v_nick} ,function(resp) {
var resp=JSON.parse(resp);
    if(resp.count){
        window.alert('Choose another nick please!');
    }
});
```

Comment: $nick_exist will return a number in the php, so the JS condition you have posted is wrong :)

Comment: if(parseInt(resp.count) > 0)

Comment: it is integer value already so no need to check on front-end.

Comment: But you must check if its bigger than 0, or it will always return true

Comment: 0 means false any non 0 is true value.

Comment: 0 is false are you sure about that? because the last time I've checked, 0 is a number and not a boolean.

Comment: I didn't really made a question.. if php returns a number, you need to expect a number and not a boolean. The worst mistake is to compare 0 to false.

Comment: if you check if(0 == false) it will give true.the way i have written is the most obvious way of writing and is correct also.negative values will also be considered as true.